# How to compare 2 sparse matrix stored using scikit-learn library load_svmlight_file?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

i am trying to compare feature vectors present in test and train data set.These feature vectors are stored in sparse format using scikitlearn library load_svmlight_file.The dimension of feature vectors of both the dataset is same.However,I am getting this error :"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()."

Why am I getting this error?
How can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
pathToTrainData="../train.txt"
pathToTestData="../test.txt"
X_train,Y_train= load_svmlight_file(pathToTrainData);
X_test,Y_test= load_svmlight_file(pathToTestData);

for ele1 in X_train:
    for ele2 in X_test:
        if(ele1==ele2):
           print "same vector"


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c1f145f984a6> in <module>()
      7 for ele1 in X_train:
      8     for ele2 in X_test:
----> 9         if(ele1==ele2):
     10            print "same vector"

/Users/rkasat/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.pyc in __bool__(self)
    181             return True if self.nnz == 1 else False
    182         else:
--> 183             raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
    184                              "element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().")
    185     __nonzero__ = __bool__

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use this condition to check whether the two sparse arrays are exactly equal without needing to densify them:

```
if (ele1 - ele2).nnz == 0:
    # Matched, do something ...
```

The `nnz` attribute gives the number of nonzero elements in the sparse array.

Some simple test runs to show the difference:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

A = sparse.rand(10, 1000000).tocsr()

def benchmark1(A):
    for s1 in A:
        for s2 in A:
            if (s1 - s2).nnz == 0:
                pass

def benchmark2(A):
    for s1 in A:
        for s2 in A:
            if (s1.toarray() == s2).all() == 0:
                pass

%timeit benchmark1(A)
%timeit benchmark2(A)
```

Some results:

```
# Computer 1
10 loops, best of 3: 36.9 ms per loop # with nnz
1 loops, best of 3: 734 ms per loop # with toarray

# Computer 2
10 loops, best of 3: 28 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 312 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice, definitely more elegant! Although copying your code makes the benchmark less severe on my laptop: ```In [6]: %timeit benchmark1(A)

1 loops, best of 3: 7.76 s per loop

In [7]: %timeit benchmark2(A)
1 loops, best of 3: 15.4 s per loop
```

:) (Then again, the random seed wasn't fixed :))

Comment: Although something must have gone horribly wrong with my computer at that time. I must recheck this

Comment: Weirdly, the benchmark stays this bad on my laptop even after restarting. This is interesting and I'll investigate it. In the meantime I wrote a new comparison function in my answer to enter into the competition :)

Comment: I haven't been able to locate my problem. The loops run in 7s and 15s respectively on my laptop (rather new dell, 8G of ram, 4 cores, anaconda, so no hardware problems a priori). Anybody have an idea why this could be? (The comparison function I wrote runs in 13ms per loop, so there is something weird going on)

Comment: OK, big computer says ```In [6]: %timeit benchmark1(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 49.8 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit benchmark2(A)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.06 s per loop
```
so that works better. Still clueless for my laptop, though. For what it's worth, the comparison function I propose gives ```In [10]: %timeit benchmark3(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: @eickenberg Now I tested on another computer, and the difference is less drastic. I'm impressed by your effort! Perhaps an explanation of how the vectorization works / proof of correctness in your answer would be good.

Comment: btw my "big computer" is a 24 core 64G "monster", and it isn't performing as well as what you indicate. However, I do not have any multithreading on matrix multiplications activated. Maybe this is the difference? Is your numpy binded with MKL by any chance?

Comment: The numpy I typically use is compiled with openblas; but for this case, I'm not sure this would make a big difference -- I tested using a "stock" numpy (packaged by ArchLinux, config [here](http://pastebin.com/TpDVN3fv)), and the results are very similar. FWIW, my CPU is i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz. Your code runs ``100 loops, best of 3: 7.1 ms per loop`` here.

Answer (score 2):

If your arrays are dense you can run into the same problem, and there the solution is straightforward. Replace

```
if(ele1==ele2):
```

with

```
if (ele1 == ele2).all():
```

However, since you are working with sparse matrices, this problem is actually not that easy in general. Notably, the functions `all` and `any` aren't implemented for sparse matrices (which, at least for `all` is understandable, because `all` can only return `True` if the matrix tested is densely filled with values that evaluate to `True`).

In your case, since you are only comparing lines of your sparse matrices, you may find it acceptable to densify them and then do the comparison. Try replacing the mentioned line by

```
if (ele1.toarray() == ele2).all():  # Densifying one of them casts the other to dense too
```

On a more general note, you seem to want to compare the lines of 2 matrices. Depending on the number of entries, this can be done a lot more efficiently by defining a vectorized comparison function, like this:

```
def compare(A, B):
    return zip(*np.where((np.array(A.multiply(A).sum(1)) +
        np.array(B.multiply(B).sum(1)).T) - 2 * A.dot(B.T).toarray() == 0))
```

This function will return a list of couples of indices, telling you which rows correspond to each other and is **a lot more efficient** than the double for loop used in your code.

**Explanation**: The function `compare` calculates pairwise euclidean distances using the binomial formula `(a - b) ** 2 == a ** 2 + b ** 2 - 2 * a * b`. This formula also works for l2 norm and scalar products. If the matrices weren't sparse, the formula would become much simpler: `squared_distances = (A ** 2).sum(axis=1) + (B ** 2).sum(axis=1) - 2 * A.dot(B.T)`. Then we check which of these entries are equal to 0 using `np.where` and return them as tuples.

Benchmarking this, we obtain:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
A = sparse.rand(10, 1000000, random_state=rng).tocsr()

In [12]: %timeit compare(A, A)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ms per loop
```